# C++ Programming Help! It wont work?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The first column contains the numbers 1 through 5
Subsequent columns contain the result of multiplying the number in the
First column by the numbers 0 through 9

Okay I got this far but its not working and i have no clue why! if you can point me in the right direction that would be very helpful :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for ( int i=0 ; i < 5; i++)
    { 
        cout << " ";
        // end for

        for ( int j = 0; j>=i; j ++) 
            cout << endl;
    }  // end for

    return 0;
}   //end of main function
```

Comment: This prints five times " " (a space character) followed by a newline. You're sure that's what you want ?

Comment: @Lily, please format your code next time.  The code you've shown seems to bear no relation to your problem - what are you asking about?

Comment: I feel compelled to down-vote questions like these... when the author clearly hasn't taken the time necessary to compose a decent question.

Comment: @John Leidegren - I'm with you.  A better question is "how did this question get an upvote?"

Comment: @John @Carl While it may seem stupid and trivial to us, I'm sure the OP had legitimate troubles and trusted us with helping him/her.  Note that Lily did not ask us to do his/her homework but instead asked for us to "point [him/her] in the right direction."  To be honest, I think it's a bit sad that a potential new member of the community got such a harsh welcome.

Answer (score 3):

> The first column contains the numbers 1 through 5 Subsequent columns contain the result of multiplying the number in the First column by the numbers 0 through 9

Hhh..

- In your snippet, the outer loop runs from 0 to 4. But the question is from 1 to 5.
- Inner loop should run form 0 through 9, which means it is independent of `i` value of outer loop. So, the condition for the inner loop `j>=i` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have the right idea with the nested loops, your current code does nothing but output a few spaces and newlines.  Let's examine your code line-by-line:

```
for ( int i=0 ; i < 5; i++)
```

The iterator in this loop will start at zero and end at four.  Although starting at zero is acceptable in many cases, it's a lot easier here to just start at 1.  So, it should be changed to this:

```
for (int = 1; i <= 5; i++)
```

Now, the next line.

```
cout << " ";
```

All this does is print a space.  You have the number, but you're not doing anything with it.  You should print `i` before the space, like so:

```
cout << i << " ";
```

We run into trouble again at your second (inner) loop.

```
for ( int j = 0; j>=i; j ++) 
    cout << endl;
```

It is good that you initialize `j` to zero.  However, your conditional, `j >= i`, means that the loop will continue executing *as long as `j` is greater or equal to `i`.*  You want it to run as long as it's less than or equal to nine.  Additionally, all you're doing inside the loop is printing a newline.  You should change it to print the product of `i` and `j`:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
    cout << (i * j) << " ";
```

When you put it all together, you should end up with something like the following code.  Note that I added some extra formatting and I changed a few identifiers for clarity.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> // Needed for std::setw, which makes sure everything lines up.

int main()
{
    for (int firstNumber = 1; firstNumber <= 5; firstNumber++)
    {
        std::cout << std::setw(3) << firstNumber << " | "; // Output the first number of the row.  This makes up the first column.

        for (int secondNumber = 0; secondNumber <= 9; secondNumber++)
        {
            std::cout << std::setw(3) << (firstNumber * secondNumber) << " "; // Output the rest of the numbers in the row.
        }

        std::cout << std::endl; // We're done with the row, so make a linebreak.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what your trying to do, your code will never work.

You want something like this:

```
for(int i=1; i <=5; i++)
{
   std::cout << i << " ";
   for(int j=0; j <=9; j++)
     std::cout << i*j << " ";

   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The formating won't be perfect but its closer to what you seem to be looking for.

Comment: You should have explained why the code doesn't work rather than giving away the answer.